# How To make Array To Input Loop For Into Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

hello I have a problem with How to load an array and loop it into dataframe in pandas and i have a code like below :

```
Tiker = ['one', 'two', 'tree', 'four']
for Tiker in Tiker:
print(Tiker)

Output:
one
two
tree
four
```

The question is how to enter the array one by one into the link we want

```
url1 = 'www.data.com/' + Tiker
lm_json = requests.get(url1).json()
df_list=pd.read_html(lm_json["componentData"])
datafin = pd.DataFrame(df_list)
```

I want to use a loop in the code above and with the end result a separate dataframe from Tiker = ['one', 'two', 'tree', 'four'] from the website that we take the data from

```
Final Ouput :

dataframe1 = one

dataframe2 = two

dataframe3 = tree

dataframe4 = four
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use loop with `for` and if necessary is possible create dictionary of DataFrames:

```
dfs = {}
for t in  Tiker:
    url1 = 'www.data.com/' + t
    lm_json = requests.get(url1).json()
    datafin = pd.read_html(lm_json["componentData"])[0]

    dfs[t] = datafin
```

Then is possible get DataFrame by key:

```
print (dfs['one'])
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but here I found a problem `ValueError: Must pass 2-d input. shape=(1, 31, 12)` `datafin = pd.DataFrame(df_list)` `raise ValueError(f"Must pass 2-d input. shape={values.shape}")`

Comment: @DwijayaMaleh - Do you need first table like change `df_list=pd.read_html(lm_json["componentData"])` to `df_list=pd.read_html(lm_json["componentData"])[0]` ?

Comment: thank you, for the help i really appreciate it,thank you